# SQLAlchemy correlated subquery TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, orm, correlated-subquery, scalar-subquery

I need to write a Python SQLAlchemy code converting this SQL query, but I cannot find a meaningful way to perform this query in SQL Alchemy.

```
SELECT *
FROM alpha AS X
WHERE X.index = (
    SELECT
        MAX(index)
    FROM
        alpha AS Y
    WHERE
        X.question = Y.question
        AND X.person = Y.person
)
```

I've tried like this but I keep getting the error `TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined` (`alpha` is a Table).

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased
from sqlalchemy import func, and_
X = aliased(alpha)
Y = aliased(alpha)
conn.execute(
    select(X).where(
        X.c.index
        == select(func.max(X.c.index))
        .where(
            and_(
                X.c.question == Y.c.question,
                X.c.person == Y.c.person,

            )
        )
        .correlate(X)
    )
)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you add what version of sqlalchemy you are using?  I receive a warning when I try this but it seems you receive an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you really just need to use [scalar_subquery()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.scalar_subquery).  As I understand it the correlate will happen automatically, you only need `correlate` if SQLAlchemy can't tell what you meant.

## Code

```py
alpha = Table("alpha", metadata,
              Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
              Column("question", String),
              Column("person", String),
              Column("index", Integer),)



Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    X = aliased(alpha, name='X')
    Y = aliased(alpha, name='Y')

    q = select(X).where(
        X.c.index
        == select(func.max(X.c.index))
        .where(
            and_(
                X.c.question == Y.c.question,
                X.c.person == Y.c.person,

            )
        ).scalar_subquery()
    )
    print (q)
```

## SQL

```sql
SELECT "X".id, "X".question, "X".person, "X".index 
FROM alpha AS "X" 
WHERE "X".index = (SELECT max("X".index) AS max_1 
FROM alpha AS "Y" 
WHERE "X".question = "Y".question AND "X".person = "Y".person)
```

**This is with Postgresql and SQLAlchemy 1.4.31.**

Comment: Tried with SQLite, it works! I had to update SQLAlchemy to version 1.4.31 from 1.3 in order to use the `scalar_subquery` command. Thanks!

Comment: Works also through MySQL, thanks. What if I need to add a join to the query `q` then?

Comment: You can just add the join like `q = q.join(beta, X.c.question == beta.c.question)` where `beta` is another table.  Sqlalchemy will put the statement in the correct order.  I usually try to flow the JOIN/WHERE/etc. as much like they would flow in SQL so you can understand it later.